# How to get parent folder name of current directory?

Tags: python

I know there are functions for finding parent directory or path such as.

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

> 'C:\Users\jahon\Desktop\Projects\CAA\Result\caa\project_folder'

Is there a function that just returns the parent folder name? In this case it should be `project_folder`.

Comment: Did you look at the other functionality in `os.path`? Read the docs!

Comment: I checked i didn't find something. maybe i am missing something

Comment: Wait, did you want parent of the current working directory or grandparent of some file? You can `os.path.split(os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))[0])[1]`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get the last part of any path using [**`basename`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) (from [**`os.path`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)):

```
>>> from os.path import basename
>>> basename('/path/to/directory')
'directory'
```

Just to note, if your path ends with `/` then the last part of the path is empty:

```
>>> basename('/path/to/directory/')
''
```

Answer (score 23):

You can achieve this easily with `os`

```
import os
os.path.basename(os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can use [PurePath](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath).

```
PurePath(__file__).parent.name == 'parent_dir'
```

Comment: Ooh! [**`pathlib`**](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html) is new to me! Looking forward to migrating from Python 2.7.0 to Python 3.4.

Comment: I am still using python 2.7 versions. Object oriented path approach is really good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split and os.path.sep to get the list of path elements and then call the last element of the list:

```
import os

path = 'C:\\Users\\jahon\\Desktop\\Projects\\CAA\\Result\\caa\\project_folder'

    if path.split(os.path.sep)[-1]:
                parent_folder = path.split(os.path.sep)[-1] # if no backslashes at the end
            else:
                parent_folder = path.split(os.path.sep)[-2] # with backslashes at the end
```